# Beautiful Soup or Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am fairly new to programming and I need a technical explanation to the below questions.

First of all, while I humbly know my way around both "Beautiful Soup" and "Selenium", I would like answers from experienced users, which are really hard to pull of the web or texts.

I am able to get data from a website by opening the page via selenium, then getting page.source for parsing through Beautiful soup. Beautiful soup on its own, does not give the html of the page, instead, it provides the source code of the whole website, which does not include the desired html of a particular page, even though the link is directly to that page!

1) Is there a way of getting the page_source without selenium, but only Beautiful Soup?

2) Can I use selenium without opening the page in question? (like is there an equivalent to .get('http..'), which will not physically open up the link! I find this to be a nightmare if dealing with > 300 links!!!!!)

2) Is there another more efficient pythonic way of doing this?

The code I am currently working with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver import chrome



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:chromedriver.exe')


url= "https.."
driver.get(url) 
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
print(soup.text)
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If your page rendered by Java Scripts  NOT static then you might not get all content using beautifulsoup. However if there any API available for the webpage then you can use that api.Can you post your url to see if it is possible by beautifulsoup or not?

Comment: the website is private. If you could elaborate on the API approach, that would be awesome.

Comment: Also sometimes, in dynamic pages, the data will be within a json format within the `<script>` tags. So if the page is dynamic and not in the html source with requests and beautifulsoup, i's 1) see if I can get the data from API (as stated by KunduK); 2) see if the data is somewhere else in the html source (likely in `<script>` tag; 3) If those don;t work, I then turn to Selenium.

Comment: @Mixter, there's tons of tutorials out there, here's one I did really quick for a friend a while back [link](https://main.weku.io/community-deals/@stats-n-lats/web-scraping-if-site-is-dynamic-generated-by-javascript)

Comment: @chitown88. while majority of the tags are <script id the data that I want is not within. My only hope now, is the API approach.

Answer (score 0):

The api approach, recommended in the comments above, is to essentially hijack the api calls being made by the web page.  If you go through the network tab of your browser and find the request being made that gets the data you are looking for, then you can mimic the same request in python.

[Curl converter](https://curlconverter.com/) is a simple tool with screenshots of what I mean.

Once you know the request that is being made you can mimic the headers to make the server think you are the website making similar requests.